# How to calculate a sum based on a date range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to find dates within 30 days in Column `B`. If the date matches the range it should sum all those that match in column `I`.

I have tried this formula:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,">="&TODAY()-30,I:I)
```

It won't work in Google Sheets. I tried moving the date outside but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `DATEVALUE` function:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,">"&DATEVALUE(TODAY()-30),I:I)
```

[image: Calculate Sum Based On Date Range in Google Sheets]

As an alternative you could place the date `=(TODAY()-30)` in a cell (eg cell `C1`) and use the formula

```
=SUMIF(B:B,">"&C1,I:I)
```

[image: SUMIF with criterion a date range from a cell]

Functions used:

- [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583)
- [DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039)
- [TODAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984)

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.